# How to view my static website without storage.googleapis.com in the address

Tags: hosting, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, static-site, google-cloud-dns

I am trying to build my first website on a domain that I purchased through Google Domains. I have followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) but am still unable to reach my site by visiting *www.mysite.com*

I have ensured that *index.html* and *404.html* are set to public-read and I can see them by clicking on the public link button in the console, but that takes me to *https://storage.googleapis.com/www.mysite.com/index.html*

I want to simply be able to type *www.mysite.com* and see my index.html document.

I have added a record set with `DNS Name` *www.mysite.com* and `Data` *c.storage.googleapis.com* but still have no luck.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

[This tool](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookup) shared by a commenter below shed a bit more light on what seems to be causing the issue. It looks like my registrar setup is not finished, but I am not sure how to do so.

I noticed that when I search for www.mysite.com, every field says `No record found`, but when I search for just mysite.com (no "www"), some fields are populated (not AAAA, CNAME, A, SPF, SRV, TXT, SRV, or LOC, though)

I also noticed the "Registrar Setup" link on the Cloud DNS page, which says "This zone will not normally be usable until you register the related domain and configure these records with your registrar:" and lists `ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com` for e1 through e4.

Why are fewer fields populated for www.mysite.com than for mysite.com, and what steps do I need to take to finish my registrar setup?

**UPDATE: ANSWERED**

I determined the issue and have posted the answer below

Comment: Is the record a CNAME record? Also, remember that DNS changes can take an hour or more to percolate out.

Comment: Yes, it is a CNAME record. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that, but thank you! I will check again very soon but as of now, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

What error do you get exactly when you go to www.mysite.com? Does it resolve? Do you get a 404? Do you get the 404 you specified? Or a 404 from Google? Or something else?

Are you sure the CNAME is set correctly? You can check it with a tool like this:
https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookup

What happens when you go to www.mysite.com/index.html ? Did you assign pages?
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#optional_assigning_pages

Comment: I see a message that says "The site can't be reached. www.mySite.com's server DNS address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", so no 404 (not the one I specified or otherwise).

I am checking the CNAME using your tool now.

When I go to www.mysite.com/index.html, I see the same issue as before, even though (yes) I assigned pages using the process in the link you provided.

Thank you for being so thorough!

UPDATE: The tool you shared shed some light, please see my update above

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: I had added my CNAME entry on the Cloud Console > Cloud DNS page, rather than on my Google Domains registry. After removing the entry from the Cloud DNS page and adding it to the Google Domains Configure DNS page, my site is up and running.